# Android Application open after click sms

Tags: android

I am trying to write code like , from my application i send a sms, and when that sms open it goes to my application and a open  specific  activity.
If application not install then nothing happen.

Any idea you have ?

Comment: What's the issue. Please post the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: Post whatever you have tried.

Comment: Your app has no control over how an arbitrary SMS client handles or displays its incoming messages. SMS is just plain text, and though most clients will linkify phone numbers, URLs, etc., there is nothing you can include in a text message to "force" an app to treat your messages any differently than it chooses. If your app is also the one to receive the messages, this would be possible, but the recipient would have to have your app installed, and choose to use it to read your specific messages.

Comment: "there is nothing you can include in a text message to "force" an app to treat your messages any differently than it chooses" Sure there is. You can write a Broadcast receiver that listens for SMS messages. You can parse the SMS text and take an action based on the content of the text. Not sure what you mean by "choose to use it to read...".

Comment: "Android Application open after click sms", "If application not install then nothing happen." - The OP is clearly talking about reading a message in an SMS client, and opening their app by clicking a link therein. If their app is installed, it certainly can process incoming messages, but that is not what was asked.

Comment: Thanks Mike M and Stealth Rabbi  for valuable idea .